# Have to click twice Like button to like page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I use a Like button on every play page (click on one of the covers from the main page) of my website (prograstreaming.com/_wb).

When I press the first time the Like button, it tells me I like it and after 2 seconds I get an error just behind it. When I press the error text, the following appears in a window:

There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/` and fixing any errors.

I tested my URL in the debug tool and it gives me the following:
Error Parsing URL:  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.

When I press for the second time the `Like` button, My page get liked without an error?

This is the code I use:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href='.$the_perma.'&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=380&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:380px; height:70px;"></iframe>
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Right, the $the_perma is not so obvious.
Here is what the $the_perma is look like:
`code`http://www.progstreaming.com/_wb/pages/play-album.php?activeAlbum=00020%20-%20Enochian%20Theory%20-%20Life...And%20All%20It%20Entails `code`

Comment: I used some code (called a droplet in the CMS i use) for facebook.

Now I put the code directly in the page and the facebook Like is working now.
Have to take a look at the droplet code.
Thanks for your suggestions.